# Cortana is not showing on my phone with United State Region

Tags: cortana

My phone is lumia 535. I have tried every trick to setting up cortana on my phone but still its not showing. My settings are below

- Region(United State)
- Language(English United State)
- Speech(English United State)

Even after these settings i check for updates. And my phone is updated.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: In Settings > About, what Carrier is listed (eg. CV GBIE)? Also, have a go at all these [possible solutions](https://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/cortana/solutions-to-cortana-issues) :)

Comment: Sorry for the Off Topic but you missed the oportunity to take those screen shots 3 minutes later.

Comment: When you changed the language and Region did you restart separately for each step? Just a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Reset my phone. And on the first boot i select

- Region(United State)
- Language(English United State)
- Speech(English United State)

And Cortana appear in my phone.